# Does Using Generics in Java Affect Performance?

Tags: java, generics

Generics have been in Java since version 5. What are the performance implications of using generics in a Java application and can you explain the reasons for their performance impact?

Comment: Affect performance compared to what?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Generics is a compile time feature. It has next to no impact when running your application.

Like most performance questions; it is far more important to write clear and simple code and this is often gives very good performance.

Changing your design for performance reasons is a so often a mistake some people say you should never do it. I think it is worth considering performance before you start but you have to recognise when you have a relatively trivial performance question.

You are better off writing your code and optimising it later when you have a better understanding of how you application behaves. i.e. when you are real use cases and a profiler.

Comment: Generics does come at a cost of the runtime type coercion (which is kind of expensive) that is added into all of your code every time you pull an object typed with generics  The actual performance cost is small but the cost builds up if you are running that section of code millions of times per second.

Comment: @JohnnyV however if you are not using generic, you will need this casting all the same, it is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Not if you don't have hard-coded versions.  I'm still trying to figure out a template engine so I can generate dozens of fully hard-typed classes (in lieu of generics) from a template class like they do with the nio buffers.

Comment: @JohnnyV This will make microbenchmarks faster however if you have a lot of these they can blow out the code cache of the CPU and you can get slower code. Impossible to know until you try it with a real application. I suggest you have a look at Koloboke which can genearte bespoke collections as templates using annotation processing

Comment: If you're interested.  I made a repo with the JMH unit tests for this https://github.com/jon-valliere/jmh-generics-benchmark  The type checking cost is huge, just depends on whether it makes an impact on the kind of application.

Comment: @JohnnyV Thank you, quite a few are optimised away to nothing and seem to be just one clock cycle.

Answer (score 10):

> ***Is it affect the performance of an application and how?***

No, it won't affect performance since it's not even there at runtime.

From the official trail:

> *When a generic type is instantiated, the compiler translates those types by a technique called type erasure — a process where the compiler removes all information related to type parameters and type arguments within a class or method.*

---

As I've illustrated [here](http://pastebin.com/CeZzX4dt) both these programs translate to the very same bytecode:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("hello");
        System.out.println(l.get(0).length());
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.*;

class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l = new ArrayList();
        l.add("hello");
        System.out.println(((String) l.get(0)).length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why they downvoted, but I can imagine some people (like me) will not agree with your explaining. What you should compare for performance is an MyClass<T> and initiate it with T=String, and a direct implementation of MyClass<String> without generics. This matters in performance. Usually not much, but when you have them in the inner loop of an algorithm, this can easily give up to 50% performance loss, as can be seen in this simple example: http://pastebin.com/QeCW0W1R (I know it's bad profiling, but just do it 5 times and then 5 times with the test order reversed, it's always the same)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it does affect performance because the compiler creates type-casts.

For example:

```
List<String> strings = ...
String first = strings.get(0);
```

will become:

```
List strings;
String first = (String)string.get(0);
```

However, this doesn't really matter because before Java had generics this was solved the same way. In Java generics only ensure type safety at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Generics do not affect runtime performance.  However, they might positively affect your development performance.  Thanks to generics, you gain extra checks during compile time, so you are able to detect certain errors faster.